# I can't add my pie chart to cvitem

Tags: tikz-pgf, moderncv

I have a pie chart as below:

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper,san]{moderncv}   % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

\moderncvstyle{classic}                        % 选项参数是 ‘casual’, ‘classic’, ‘oldstyle’ 和 ’banking’
\moderncvcolor{blue}                          % 选项参数是 ‘blue’ (默认)、‘orange’、‘green’、‘red’、‘purple’ 和 ‘grey’

\name{a}{a}
\title{s}
\address{}{s}
\email{}
\phone[mobile]{1212}
\begin{document}

\cvitem{}{
\def\angle{0}
\def\radius{3}
\def\cyclelist{{"orange","blue","red","green"}}
\newcount\cyclecount \cyclecount=-1
\newcount\ind \ind=-1
\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes = {font=\sffamily}]
  \foreach \percent/\name in {
      8/C++,8/Linux,7/Arduino,6/Python,6/Erlang,5/H5
    } {
      \ifx\percent\empty\else               % If \percent is empty, do nothing
        \global\advance\cyclecount by 1     % Advance cyclecount
        \global\advance\ind by 1            % Advance list index
        \ifnum3<\cyclecount                 % If cyclecount is larger than list
          \global\cyclecount=0              %   reset cyclecount and
          \global\ind=0                     %   reset list index
        \fi
        \pgfmathparse{\cyclelist[\the\ind]} % Get color from cycle list
        \edef\color{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store as \color
        % Draw angle and set labels
        \draw[fill={\color!50},draw={\color}] (0,0) -- (\angle:\radius)
          arc (\angle:\angle+\percent*1.8*2.5:\radius) -- cycle;

        \node at (\angle+0.5*\percent*1.8*2.5:0.7*\radius) {\name};
        %\node[pin=\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\name]
        %  at (\angle+0.5*\percent*3.6:\radius) {};
        \pgfmathparse{\angle+\percent*1.8*2.5}  % Advance angle
        \xdef\angle{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store in \angle
      \fi
    };
\end{tikzpicture}}

\clearpage
\end{document}
```

But when I copy them into `\cvitem{}{$here}`. I got lots of error.

> file: 'file:///c%3A/Users/erow/Documents/tex/cv1.tex'
>   severity: '错误'
>   message: 'Paragraph ended before \cvitem was complete                      \par  l.74
>   '
>   at: '74,1'
>   source: 'LaTeX'
>   code: 'undefined'
>
> file: 'file:///c%3A/Users/erow/Documents/tex/cv1.tex'
>   severity: '错误'
>   message: 'Undefined control sequence \pgffor@body ...else \global \advance \cyclecount                                                    by 1 \global \advance \ind... l.98     }           ; c:/Users/erow/Documents/tex/cv1.tex:98: You can't use `the letter b' after \advance. \pgffor@body ...lse \global \advance \cyclecount b                                                   y 1 \global \advance \ind ... l.98     }           ; c:/Users/erow/Documents/tex/cv1.tex:98: Undefined control sequence. \pgffor@body ...ecount by 1 \global \advance \ind                                                    by 1 \ifnum 3<\cyclecount ... l.98     }           ; c:/Users/erow/Documents/tex/cv1.tex:98: You can't use`the letter b' after \advance. \pgffor@body ...count by 1 \global \advance \ind b                                                   y 1 \ifnum 3<\cyclecount ... l.98     }           ; c:/Users/erow/Documents/tex/cv1.tex:98: Undefined control sequence. \pgffor@body ...ce \ind by 1 \ifnum 3<\cyclecount                                                    \global \cyclecount =0 \gl... l.98     }           ; c:/Users/erow/Documents/tex/cv1.tex:98: Missing number, treated as zero.                      \global  l.98     }           ; c:/Users/erow/Documents/tex/cv1.tex:98: Undefined control sequence.  \cyclelist                        [\the \ind ] l.98     }           ; c:/Users/erow/Documents/tex/cv1.tex:98: Undefined control sequence.  \cyclelist [\the \ind                                   ] l.98     }           ; c:/Users/erow/Documents/tex/cv1.tex:98: You can't use `the character ]' after \the.  \cyclelist [\the \ind ]
>   '
>   at: '98,1'
>   source: 'LaTeX'
>   code: 'undefined'

Comment: The example is all right. And the only thing I want is moving it to cvitem. Or some other way to make it in center. It looks ugly.囧

Comment: It need `moderncv` package. You can install it in pakcage manager.

Comment: Problem is a a blank line.o(╯□╰)o

Comment: Thanks for updating :-). This is now really clear and useful: very easy for people to reproduce the problem. (You are still welcome, by the way - but I've managed to lose the greeting in deleting my no-longer-needed comments asking for a useful example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I guess that an MNWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper,san]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\name{a}{a}
\title{s}
\address{}{s}
\email{}
\phone[mobile]{1212}
\begin{document}

\cvitem{}{%
  \def\angle{0}
  \def\radius{3}
  \def\cyclelist{{"orange","blue","red","green"}}
  \newcount\cyclecount \cyclecount=-1
  \newcount\ind \ind=-1
  \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes = {font=\sffamily}]
    \foreach \percent/\name in {
      8/C++,8/Linux,7/Arduino,6/Python,6/Erlang,5/H5
    } {
      \ifx\percent\empty\else               % If \percent is empty, do nothing
      \global\advance\cyclecount by 1     % Advance cyclecount
      \global\advance\ind by 1            % Advance list index
      \ifnum3<\cyclecount                 % If cyclecount is larger than list
      \global\cyclecount=0              %   reset cyclecount and
      \global\ind=0                     %   reset list index
      \fi
      \pgfmathparse{\cyclelist[\the\ind]} % Get color from cycle list
      \edef\color{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store as \color
      % Draw angle and set labels
      \draw[fill={\color!50},draw={\color}] (0,0) -- (\angle:\radius) arc (\angle:\angle+\percent*1.8*2.5:\radius) -- cycle;

      \node at (\angle+0.5*\percent*1.8*2.5:0.7*\radius) {\name};
      \pgfmathparse{\angle+\percent*1.8*2.5}  % Advance angle
      \xdef\angle{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store in \angle
      \fi
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\clearpage
\end{document}
```

which returns

```
Runaway argument?
{\def \angle {0} \def \radius {3} \def \cyclelist {{"orange","blue","\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \\cvitem was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.45 

?
```

The problem here is that you have a paragraph break in the argument to `\cvitem` i.e. a blank line. So, a minimal fix would be

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper,san]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\name{a}{a}
\title{s}
\address{}{s}
\email{}
\phone[mobile]{1212}
\begin{document}
\cvitem{pie chart}{%
  \def\angle{0}
  \def\radius{3}
  \def\cyclelist{{"orange","blue","red","green"}}
  \newcount\cyclecount \cyclecount=-1
  \newcount\ind \ind=-1
  \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes = {font=\sffamily}]
    \foreach \percent/\name in {
      8/C++,8/Linux,7/Arduino,6/Python,6/Erlang,5/H5
    } {
      \ifx\percent\empty\else               % If \percent is empty, do nothing
      \global\advance\cyclecount by 1     % Advance cyclecount
      \global\advance\ind by 1            % Advance list index
      \ifnum3<\cyclecount                 % If cyclecount is larger than list
      \global\cyclecount=0              %   reset cyclecount and
      \global\ind=0                     %   reset list index
      \fi
      \pgfmathparse{\cyclelist[\the\ind]} % Get color from cycle list
      \edef\color{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store as \color
      % Draw angle and set labels
      \draw[fill={\color!50},draw={\color}] (0,0) -- (\angle:\radius) arc (\angle:\angle+\percent*1.8*2.5:\radius) -- cycle;
      \node at (\angle+0.5*\percent*1.8*2.5:0.7*\radius) {\name};
      \pgfmathparse{\angle+\percent*1.8*2.5}  % Advance angle
      \xdef\angle{\pgfmathresult}         %   and store in \angle
      \fi
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image: minimal fix]

However, you really shouldn't use this code. For one thing it redefines `\color` in an environment which uses colours a lot. The redefinition is only local, but that still seems dubious. Moreover `\name` is serving as both a local variable and a macro taking arguments, which is confusing. And it is not obvious that the `\global` definitions are not going to wipe out something crucial, either.

Moreover, you don't need to do any of these dangerous things. The following should be considerably safer:

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper,san]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\name{a}{a}
\title{s}
\address{}{s}
\email{}
\phone[mobile]{1212}
\begin{document}

\cvitem{}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
    % these are local - much less likely to cause problems
    \def\radius{3}
    \def\cyclelist{{"orange","blue","red","green"}}
    \foreach \percent/\pname [evaluate=\percent as \pangle using ((4.5*\percent)+\panglelast)) , remember=\pangle as \panglelast (initially 0), count=\cyclecount from 0] in 
    {
      8/C++,8/Linux,7/Arduino,6/Python,6/Erlang,5/H5
    } {
      \pgfmathsetmacro\mycolor{\cyclelist[(int(mod(\cyclecount,4)))]}
      % Draw angle and set labels
      \draw [fill={\mycolor!50}, draw={\mycolor}] (0,0) -- (\panglelast:\radius) arc (\panglelast:\pangle:\radius) -- cycle;
      \node at ({(\pangle+\panglelast)/2}:0.7*\radius) {\pname};
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\end{document}
```

and produces exactly the same result (except that I've lost the label of the `\cvitem` somewhere along the line.

To de-squish the labels, you might also prefer something which looks more like the following:

[image: de-squished labels]

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper,san]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\name{a}{a}
\title{s}
\address{}{s}
\email{}
\phone[mobile]{1212}
\begin{document}

\cvitem{}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
    % these are local - much less likely to cause problems
    \def\radius{3}
    \def\cyclelist{{"orange","blue","red","green"}}
    \foreach \percent/\pname [evaluate=\percent as \pangle using ((4.5*\percent)+\panglelast)) , remember=\pangle as \panglelast (initially 0), count=\cyclecount from 0] in 
    {
      8/C++,8/Linux,7/Arduino,6/Python,6/Erlang,5/H5
    } {
      \pgfmathsetmacro\mycolor{\cyclelist[(int(mod(\cyclecount,4)))]}
      % Draw angle and set labels
      \draw [fill={\mycolor!50}, draw={\mycolor}] (0,0) -- (\panglelast:\radius) arc (\panglelast:\pangle:\radius) -- cycle;
      \path (0,0) -- ({(\pangle+\panglelast)/2}:\radius) node [midway, sloped] {\pname};
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: God!Does a blank line have special meaning?

Comment: @erow A blank line is a paragraph break. Are you new to LaTeX? This is the way you start a new paragraph in LaTeX (or in any TeX, for that matter). Please also see my edits above. That `\edef\color` and the `\global`s really aren't wise and can, I think, be easily avoided. (Or do you really need to include empty values for `\percent`?)

Comment: I started latex two days ago. And I don't know what is`empty values for \percent`

Comment: @erow Your original code allows you to add something like `/Perl` to your list without error. But I don't know why you'd want this in a pie chart: either Perl needs a slice and should get a number or it doesn't and should be dropped. My code assumes you use value-pairs which makes sense and will give an error if you don't. I don't know why you'd need empty values, so, if you don't either, you probably don't need them. But, after all, you posted the code. I therefore mentioned it because i assume you had some reason for writing it that way.

Comment: You want to know the meaning of  pair "8/C++" ? I use the percent to change size, and don't want to show it.

Comment: @erow Yes, I know. It is fine as long as you don't want to write `/C++` i.e. with no number. Just use a number and the code I posted will work fine.